# Misconception about how the scales work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a beginner in Unity and I can't understand how the scales of GameObjects work; in the following picture I have a quad and a sprite. The quad's scale should be smaller than the sprite's scale, but in the editor when I touch them they have the same scale of 1.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Every object has a baseline `(1, 1, 1)` scale when first created. The **size** for a 2D sprite and 3D quad object are calculated differently for each, which is why they are not the same size in your screenshot.

**Long Answer**

The sprite is a 2D object and its size is based on the import settings of the sprite. The default size for sprites is 100 pixels is 1 unit.

The quad is a 3D object and its size is based on what 1 unit is in Unity. In Unity's settings, 1 unit is 1 meter, by default. So, the quad is 1 meter cubed, by default.

If you import a sprite that is `100x100`, and keep the default 100 pixels is 1 unit, it should be the same size (with an orthographic camera) as the default quad size.

Comment: That's a nice answer!